# change Winform Icon Failure .But when i delete the shortcut file of my application.Changes Worked

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, inno-setup

I tried to change my application Icon when starting up but failed.

The code goes like:

this.Icon =。。。

But it only works when I delete my application's shortcut file, which is created by a package tool named InnoSetup.

Has anyone met a similar situation?

Comment: Do you expect that runtime change of the application icon changes a desktop shortcut icon? Or what?

Comment: yes. I found  icons shown in the taksbar is the same as the icon in shortcut file .

Answer (score 0):

In the form design, if you select the form itself there's an option to just have a different icon, but first i would add the icon to your project.

[image]

this should automatically add the following code into the Form1.Designer.cs

```
this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
```

That's how i always did it on mine.

Comment: THKS.but this is not solution to my problem.

Comment: I want to change icons int taskbar of my application in runtime  by programming.